# How can I delete or hide this output window in the flexdashboard?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, flexdashboard

I was working on a map for a dashboard in flexdashboard in R, but no matter how hard I try, I can't delete this output from the final dashboard, does anyone have a solution? I've already looked everywhere but I can't find anything on the subject. I give you the code for that part and an image of what I want to erase (
Thanks for reading and helping me):

````
    ```{r mapa, echo=FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=15, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

options(scipen = 999)

#Cargar Shapefile
mapamundial <- readOGR("/Users/jorge/Downloads/Paises_Mundo/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp")

#Crear un archivo cvs para verificar nombres

write.csv(mapamundial@data, file = "/Users/jorge/Downloads/basenombre.csv")

mapamun_polig <- fortify(mapamundial, region = "NAME")

basecoordenadas <- read_excel("/Users/jorge/Desktop/Trabajo/Tamsa/Basedashboard/basecoordenadas.xlsx")

names(basecoordenadas) <- c("id", "Poblacion")

#unir datos

mapafinal <- merge(mapamun_polig, basecoordenadas, by = "id", all = TRUE)

names (mapafinal)[8] = "Acero"

mapafinal <- mapafinal [order(mapafinal$order), ]


mapadin <- ggplot(mapafinal, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))+
geom_polygon(aes(fill = Acero))+ theme_bw()+labs(fill = "Miles de toneladas")+
xlab("Longitud") + 
ylab("Latitud")+ 
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold", hjust = 0)) + 
theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0)) + 
theme(plot.caption = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0)) +
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) +
labs(
title = "Producción de acero por países",
subtitle = "Hasta octubre",
caption = "Fuente: Elaboración propia."
)

ggplotly(mapadin)

```
````

[Image of the part I want to erase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFRsK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Split up the large code chunk into many smaller ones. Then you can add arguments to hide the results of the data processing chunk (`results='hide'`)

````
```{r processing, echo=FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=15, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='hide'}

options(scipen = 999)

#Cargar Shapefile
mapamundial <- readOGR("/Users/jorge/Downloads/Paises_Mundo/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp")

#Crear un archivo cvs para verificar nombres

write.csv(mapamundial@data, file = "/Users/jorge/Downloads/basenombre.csv")

mapamun_polig <- fortify(mapamundial, region = "NAME")

basecoordenadas <- read_excel("/Users/jorge/Desktop/Trabajo/Tamsa/Basedashboard/basecoordenadas.xlsx")

names(basecoordenadas) <- c("id", "Poblacion")

#unir datos

mapafinal <- merge(mapamun_polig, basecoordenadas, by = "id", all = TRUE)

names (mapafinal)[8] = "Acero"

mapafinal <- mapafinal [order(mapafinal$order), ]
```

```{r mapa, echo=FALSE, fig.height=10, fig.width=15, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
mapadin <- ggplot(mapafinal, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))+
geom_polygon(aes(fill = Acero))+ theme_bw()+labs(fill = "Miles de toneladas")+
xlab("Longitud") + 
ylab("Latitud")+ 
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold", hjust = 0)) + 
theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0)) + 
theme(plot.caption = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0)) +
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) +
labs(
title = "Producción de acero por países",
subtitle = "Hasta octubre",
caption = "Fuente: Elaboración propia."
)

ggplotly(mapadin)

```
````